# How can we plot a parametric curve in a Lorentzian space using Mathematica.

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematica, semi-riemannian-geometry

We have the following informations:

The components of a metric tensor are given by $g_{11}=-2z, g_{22}=4x^{2}+2z, g_{33}=1,g_{23}=g_{32}=2x$, where $(x,y,z)$ are standard cartesian coordinates where $z$ is positive.

The equation of a parametric curve is

$\gamma \left(s\right)=\left(\surd s,- \surd s,s\right),s>0$

By calculation we obtained

$\kappa = \tau = \frac{1}{s}$, this is a generalized helix in a $3$-dimensional lorentzian space.

Using Mathematica the curve is ploted in $3$-dimensional Euclidean space as $ParametricPlot3D \left[ \left\lbrace \surd s, -\surd s, s \right\rbrace , \left\lbrace s, 0, 30 \right\rbrace \right]$

[$\gamma \left( s\right)$ in a $3$-dimensional Euclidean space (figure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aURWX.png)

then I want to plot a parametric curve $\gamma \left(s\right)$ in a Lorentzian space. 
I am new to mathematica and I have no idea how to do this, so could someone please help me to solve this.
\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

The description of a parametric curve $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is entirely **independent** of the metric you put on $\mathbb{R}^3$. That is to say, once you have chosen a coordinate system on your Minkowski $\mathbb{R}^3$, as a (smooth, topological) manifold it is entirely indistinguishable from the Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$. So the same plot should do exactly the job.